# Driver for new Canon ink-tank printers?

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I would be tempted by the potential economy of the new Canon ink-tank printers, particularly the Pixma G5050.
But as far as I can see, there are no Linux drivers available on any of the usual Canon sites (Europe, USA, Asia...).

I can't find any reference to it on any of the CUPS sites I have tried...

Does that mean no way to use these printers with Ubuntu?

Thanks for any confirmation (or preferably for a solution!).

Comment: Is your printer shown under `Settings` > `Printers`?

Answer (score 2):

> there are no Linux drivers available

yes there are

canon-europe.com > support > [drivers](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/) > [pixma g5050](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_g_series/pixma-g5050.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux) > [linux 64 bit](https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_g_series/pixma-g5050.html?type=drivers&language=en&os=linux%20(64-bit))
IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.90 for Linux, Release date: 10 September 2019

PPD file is `cnijfilter2-source-5.90-1/ppd/canong5000.ppd`

in CUPS the driver is `Canon G5000 series`

in arch-linux the driver package is [cnijfilter2](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=cnijfilter2)

the driver [fails to remove temporary files](https://github.com/milahu/canon-pixma-g5050-printer/issues/2) after use
as workaround i use

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# remove canon printer temp files older than x minutes
# run this script as root
minutes=5
# temp_path: folder with the cnij* temporary files
temp_path=/var/tmp # arch linux
#temp_path=/var/tmp/*cups*/tmp # nixos linux
while true
do    
  date    
  find $temp_path -maxdepth 1 -name 'cnij*' -mmin +${minutes} \
    -exec rm -v '{}' \;
  sleep ${minutes}m
done
```